# Why I cant call function onChange of input? HTML/jQuery

Tags: javascript

I have two input fields and I want to reflect the value of the first input as a minimum value of the second one but it is not calling the function which I built for that reason:

```js
var quantity_gates = document.getElementById('quantity_gates');
var quantity_spots = document.getElementById('quantity_spots');

function count_spots() {
  var quantity_spots_n = quantity_spots.value;
  var quantity_gates_n = quantity_gates.value;
  quantity_gates_n = Number(quantity_gates_n);
  quantity_spots_n = Number(quantity_spots_n);

  quantity_spots_n = Math.min(quantity_gates_n, Math.max(1, quantity_gates_n));
}
```

```html
<input type="number" onChange="count_spots()" id="quantity_gates" value="1" name="quantity_parking_gates" min="1" max="9999">
<input type="number" id="quantity_spots" value="1" name="quantity_parking_spots" min="1" max="9999">
```

Comment: You need to set the `value` property of the field, not the `quantity_spots_n` variable. Also check that your JS code runs after the DOM has loaded. Put it before `</body>` or wrap it in a DOMContentLoaded event handler. Also note that 'ajax', 'jquery' and 'html' are not relevant to the problem so I removed the tags

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thanks rory I tried placing it right before `</body>` but doesn't work.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan sorry it does call it now but it is not changing the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly use unobtrusive event handlers instead of `onX` attributes. The latter are outdated and no longer good practice. You can also use the `input` event to have the UI be more responsive to user input. In addition you can use the unary operator as a shorthand for the `Number()` function, and `||` to default the value to `1`.

To solve your issue you need to set the `value` property of the second field directly as it holds a string value, not a reference to the value property. Also, use `Math.max()` to set the second field to the higher of the two values.

```js
var quantity_gates = document.getElementById('quantity_gates');
var quantity_spots = document.getElementById('quantity_spots');

quantity_gates.addEventListener('input', function() {
  quantity_spots.min = this.value;
  quantity_spots.value = Math.max(this.value, +quantity_spots.value || 1);
});

quantity_spots.addEventListener('change', function() {
  this.value = Math.max(+this.value, +this.min);
});
```

```html
<input type="number" id="quantity_gates" value="1" name="quantity_parking_gates" min="1" max="9999">
<input type="number" id="quantity_spots" value="1" name="quantity_parking_spots" min="1" max="9999">
```

Comment: AMAZING, Thanks! How can I actually block user from decreasing the second number afterwards?

Comment: Set the `min` on the field to match the other's `value`. You would also need a `change` event handler to set the value equal to the min if the user manually typed a lower value. I've updated the example in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to asign the min in the second field :
by adding in the end of your function

```
quantity_spots.value=quantity_spots_n; // to assign value
quantity_spots.min=quantity_spots_n; // to prevent user from decrasing the value
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var quantity_gates = document.getElementById('quantity_gates');
var quantity_spots = document.getElementById('quantity_spots');

function count_spots() {
  var quantity_spots_n = quantity_spots.value;
  var quantity_gates_n = quantity_gates.value;
  quantity_gates_n = Number(quantity_gates_n);
  quantity_spots_n = Number(quantity_spots_n);

  quantity_spots_n = Math.min(quantity_gates_n, Math.max(1, quantity_gates_n));
  quantity_spots.min= quantity_spots_n //Sets the new minimum
  quantity_spots.value= quantity_spots_n //Sets the value 
}
```

```html
<input type="number" onChange="count_spots()" id="quantity_gates" value="1" name="quantity_parking_gates" min="1" max="9999">
<input type="number" id="quantity_spots" value="1" name="quantity_parking_spots" min="1" max="9999">
```

Comment: thanks. I can still input a lower number but it works with the arrows so I cant decrease it.